# Nativescript mapbox ontap and marker icon doesn't working

Tags: typescript, mapbox, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, mapbox-marker

Hi I have a little problem with Mapbox nativescript plugin with angular 2. Show map working fine. But when I try to load more markers then custom icon doesn't work and on tap event too. I am very desperated now, cuz I dont know what to do.

This is how my component looks. 
https://github.com/b4rtt/geoapp/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.page.ts

- problematic is part of loadPoints()

And full repository is here. 
https://github.com/b4rtt/geoapp

I will be very grateful if anyone could help me. Author of the plugin doesn't comunicate...

Comment: Author of the plugin is a bit swamped, that's all.

Comment: And do you know when you will have a little time to check it pls?

Comment: That depends on other issues in various repo's, (hopefully) a holiday, birthdays, my dayjob, the cat, my kids, the wife. So no, impossible to say, but it's on my mind every single day.

Comment: Oh in the meanwhile please clone and run the demo to see what's different in your app. It shows how to add markers with tap events from an XML loaded map. {N} 2.5 version: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox-demo/blob/2a3ccc1330f209d3fae9c83a38f1b9ec21ecc034/Mapbox/app/main-page.js#L19-L20, and here's the {N} 3.x version: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox/blob/24c915222809c57a4fffc92f1775129baff6772a/demo/app/main-page.ts#L23-L28, please let me know if that works for you. If not I'll try and prioritize.

Comment: But I using this plug-in with Angular. Maybe there could be problem

Comment: Sorry, I know that could be anoying, I really understand you. But still any progress. It's strange, because showing markers is working but they has default icon and tap event doesn't working too. Problematic is only part in loadpoints(). Load marker in constuctor is working fine. https://github.com/b4rtt/geoapp/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.page.ts